# can i use this formula for multiple column?

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, google-sheets-formula

i use query formula in google sheet to sum column and show up in the main sheet (filtered by the date entered by the user)

```
=TRANSPOSE(QUERY('DB_SAÍDA'!A3:CZ; "select sum(D) where A > date '"&TEXT(H7; "yyyy-mm-dd")&"' "; 1))
```

I was able to use it in a column (D) with this formula. But, my range have 83 column.  How can I edit this formula to cover all columns?

formula; solution; idea; something;

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Google Sheets Query sum indeterminate number of columns](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58845367/google-sheets-query-sum-indeterminate-number-of-columns)

Comment: i can use "sum(d), sum(e), sum (f), sum(g).... but is too much column. i just need select multiple column

Comment: `i just need select multiple column` The answer to "Google Sheets Query sum indeterminate number of columns" handles ANY number of columns (an indeterminate number). Use the `infinitely expanding` formula.

Comment: the post @Tedinoz seems like it could work for your needs. if you want help with this, it would be helpful to have a sample google sheet to use.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This answer is based on the formula provided by @player0 in [Google Sheets Query sum indeterminate number of columns](https://stackoverflow.com/a/58846200/1330560)

`=ARRAYFORMULA(query(QUERY({'DB_SAÍDA'!A3:CZ}, "select "&TEXTJOIN(",", 1, "sum(Col"&(ROW('DB_SAÍDA'!A1:A104))&")")), "offset 1",))`

There are several factors important to understanding the formula:

- `ARRAYFORMULA` creates a repeatable elements to cover the entire range.
- Column CZ = Column#104
- `TEXTJOIN` will create a string that reads `sum(Col1), sum(Col2, sum(Col3),... sum(Col104)`
- The column number in TEXTJOIN is created by using `ROW`; hence `A1:A104`.

So, if  So, if.the number of columns to be summed (A3:CZ) = 104

`TEXTJOIN` creaes a comma separated

---

**Sample data**

[image: data]

---

**Results**

[image: results]

---

**ADDENDUM - All formulas in referenced answer PLUS `DATE` criteria**

*Row-Based*
`=ARRAYFORMULA(query(QUERY({'DB_SAÍDA02'!A3:CZ}, "select "&TEXTJOIN(",", 1, "sum(Col"&(ROW('DB_SAÍDA02'!A2:A104))&")")&" where Col1 > date '"&TEXT('DB_SAÍDA02'!$B$1, "yyyy-mm-dd")&"'"), "offset 1",))`

*Column-Based*
`=ARRAYFORMULA(query(QUERY({'DB_SAÍDA02'!A3:CZ}, "select "&TEXTJOIN(",", 1, "sum(Col"&(COLUMN('DB_SAÍDA02'!B1:CZ))&")")&" where Col1 > date '"&TEXT('DB_SAÍDA02'!$B$1, "yyyy-mm-dd")&"'"), "offset 1",))`

*Infinitely Expanding (to columns in source)*
`=ARRAYFORMULA(query(QUERY({INDIRECT(ADDRESS(1, 1, 4,true,"DB_SAÍDA02")&":"&SUBSTITUTE(ADDRESS(1, COLUMNS('DB_SAÍDA02'!1:1), 4), 1, ))},  "select "&TEXTJOIN(",", 1, "sum(Col"&ROW(INDIRECT(ADDRESS(2, 1, 4,true,"DB_SAÍDA02")&":A"&COLUMNS('DB_SAÍDA02'!1:1)))&")")&" where Col1 > date '"&TEXT(datevalue('DB_SAÍDA02'!$B$1),"yyyy-mm-dd")&"'"), "offset 1",))`

---

**RESULTS**

[image: results02]

---

**DATA (Sheet="DB_SAÍDA02"**
[image: data02]

Comment: Maybe you could just choose: `...sum(Col"&(COLUMN ('DB_SAÍDA'!D1:CZ1))&...` and you don't need to count columns

Comment: Actually it could be a good adaptation for choosing ranges of columns. For example, If you need to sum from columns D to Z, AF to AS, and BW to CF you should be able to do it like this: `=ARRAYFORMULA(query(QUERY({'DB_SAÍDA'!A3:CZ}, "select "&TEXTJOIN(",", 1, "sum(Col"&(ROW({'DB_SAÍDA'!D1:Z1,'DB_SAÍDA'!Af1:AS1,'DB_SAÍDA'!BW1:CF1}))&")")), "offset 1",)`

Comment: @Martín Good catch. Yeah, didn't spend enough time on it.  Player0 actually had three solutions. the substitution of `Column` for `Row` and his #2, which I didn't read ;).

Comment: You're right, player0 did say that in that answer. Good for you for digging it out and adapting it!

Answer (score 1):

Maybe you can adapt to your needs, but you can try with FILTER to choose desired date and BYCOL to do the sum:

```
=BYCOL(FILTER(D3:CZ,A3:A=H7),LAMBDA(r, SUM(r)))
```

Comment: OP wants date greater than, maybe `=BYCOL(FILTER(B3:CZ,A3:A>$B$1),LAMBDA(r, SUM(r)))`

Comment: This is by far the better solution - short, sweet, simple. Though, to be fair, `BYCOL` was not available when @player0 wrote their answer.

Comment: You're right, OP said greater, I misread that. I think both solutions are useful! I usually prefer to use FILTER in combination with BYROW,BYCOL, MAKEARRAY to emulate QUERY functionalities. Now LET is too a great help in this! QUERY has its limitations like types of data per column, but it's a powerful tool; so I think it's useful to have both solutions handy 