# Google sheet - Query don't work with this code

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-formula

i try use this solution, but don't work in my sheet. so, i create same sheet than this author, but results Formula parsing error

```
=ARRAYFORMULA(QUERY({A1:E2}, "select "&TEXTJOIN(",", 1, "sum(Col"&ROW(A1:A5)&")")))
```

https://i.stack.imgur.com/mKPHk.png

original post with this query code
[Google Sheets Query sum indeterminate number of columns](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58845367/google-sheets-query-sum-indeterminate-number-of-columns)

EXAMPLE SHEET USING THIS CODE:
https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1uxmWeWwcgm8d_lOOZP0C--trq9PYbVUnEXPvfETFHQc/edit?usp=sharing

solution for this problem ?

Comment: How are you inputting the formula into your google sheet? I just tested the function: `=ARRAYFORMULA(QUERY({A1: E2}, "select " & TEXTJOIN(",", 1, "sum(Col" & ROW(A1: A5) & ")")))` and it worked for me with the same data.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If your sheet locale uses `;` convention instead of `comma` then you may want to change all the `,` in the formula.

```
=ARRAYFORMULA(QUERY({A1:E2}; "select "&TEXTJOIN(","; 1; "sum(Col"&ROW(A1:A5)&")")))
```

Comment: Thanks! is because that. Thank you, so much!!! S2