# Google-sheets query dynamic indirect reference

Tags: google-sheets, dynamic

Continuing the study of google sheets queries I found this issue:

=query({$A$2:$G};"select Col1 where Col"&join(" OR Col";INDICE(sequence(1;6;2)&"="**&(INDIRETTO("R1C"&SEQUENCE(1;$M$19;RIF.COLONNA();1);FALSO)**))))

In M20 I tryied to substitute the fixed indirect reference  "R1C"&"12"(L1) with a dynamic reference as in the first part of formula.
The target is to have just one **query** formula in order to extracting datas confrontig from rows and columns values.

The expected result is to have a one query formuala that in the second part of where clause (comparing) adpapt automatically quantity and values from row 1 avoiding to drag the formula for all the columns at right.

In L20 Itried the formula with indirect addressing, in M20 I tried to do what stated above, but doesn't work

Here is the sheet
[new](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1y3UhNZjSbYck2MKptE8kd_2_Jj6UkFZbaIWI8kMsevs/edit#gid=1706006748)

Comment: Hi. Your question must stand on its own. Please don't expect that users can/will/should open your spreadsheet in order to better understand your question, date, layout, the purpose of the query or the expected result. All of this information should be in the body of your question. Please edit your question to supply this information.

Comment: `Basicly I'd like to have just one query formula that resolve the where clause by matching the value of the columns with the value of the row ( (R1C12:R1C51) cell by cell instead of drag the formula as you can see in M2,N2,O2,P2,Q2 etc. Mybe it's not possible because query function works only in columns?` I think that would be problematic because `query` does not dynamically accept changes in variables (cell M2->N2, etc,). OTOH, one might consider how the variables are determined in the first instance, and then look at creating a single, two-step formula to deal with both processes.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

`=ARRAYFORMULA(QUERY({$A$2:$G}, "select Col1 where Col1 is not null and ("&arrayformula(TEXTJOIN("or ", 1, "Col"&ROW($A$2:$A$7)&" = "&M19&" "))&")"))`

adapted from the answer by @player0 in [Google Sheets Query sum indeterminate number of columns](https://stackoverflow.com/a/58846200/1330560)

---

**SAMPLE**

[image: sample]

Comment: Thank you but I think it isn't what I'm expecting to maybe because of my description. Basicly I'd like to have just one query formula that resolve the where clause by matching the value of the columns with the value of the row ( (R1C12:R1C51) cell by cell instead of drag the formula as you can see in M2,N2,O2,P2,Q2 etc. Mybe it's not possible because query function works only in columns?